# NewApi lint different behaviour

Tags: android, kotlin, lint

The code where min api level is 21:

```kotlin
interface SampleInterface {

    fun interfaceFun() {
        val value = HashMap<String, String>().getOrDefault("a", "b")
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun companionFun() {

        }
    }
}
```

IDE sees two issues:
[image]
[image]

1. `getOrDefault` requires api level 24
2. `@JvmStatic` for companion method also requires api level 24

`./gradlew lintDebug` aborts build only for issue 1, but not issue 2. What's the difference?

Comment: What makes you think `@JvmStatic` requires API level 24?

Comment: @ianhanniballake IDE alert. And it's visible only in `Intellij Ultimate` by the way, not in `Android Studio`. Updated the question with alert.

Comment: Sounds like IntelliJ Ultimate isn't aware that this is fully supported on all API levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Supported Java 8 language features and APIs chart](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features), default and static interface methods are supported on all API levels of Android.